# Solving 8 puzzle using A* algorithm and Manhattan Heuristic

Tags: java, algorithm

I have written a program to solve the 8 puzzle using the A* algorithm and the Manhattan heuristic but the programs doesn't seem to work correctly ( minimum number of moves ) for all the inputs and even for the correct output, the number of states expanded is much larger than what it should normally be.

My program has four classes:
Game State: To represent the Game
AStar: AStar algorithm
AStarList: A data structure for representing the open and closed lists. (I know that my data structure is very bad in terms of performance. I will improve it later on)
Utilities

Here is part of the code:

(Sorry for the large code size. I suspect that something is wrong with my AStar algorithm. So, you probably need not go through the other classes.)

AStar

```
public class AStar {

    public static void solve(GameState gameStateToSolve) {
        AStarList openList = new AStarList();
        AStarList closedlList = new AStarList();
        openList.add(gameStateToSolve);
        int iteration = 1;
        while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println((iteration++));
            GameState current = openList.getNext();
            if (current.isGoalState()) {
                current.print();
                return;
            }
            GameState children[] = current.expand();
            closedlList.addWithoutDuplication(current);
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean presentInOpenList = openList.isPresent(children[i]);
                boolean presentInClosedList = closedlList.isPresent(children[i]);
                if (!presentInOpenList && !presentInClosedList) {
                    openList.add(children[i]);
                } else if (presentInClosedList && !presentInOpenList) {
                    if (closedlList.getCostOf(children[i]) > children[i].getMovementsCount()) {
                        closedlList.remove(children[i]);
                        openList.add(children[i]);
                    }
                } else if (presentInOpenList && !presentInClosedList) {
                    if (openList.getCostOf(children[i]) > children[i].getMovementsCount()) {
                        openList.remove(children[i]);
                        openList.add(children[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        solve(new GameState(
                new int[]{0,7,3,1,8,6,5,4,2},
                new ArrayList<Integer>(),
                GameState.NUMBERS_ARRAY));
    }
}
```

AStarList

```
public class AStarList {

    ArrayList<GameState> list;

    public AStarList() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean isPresent(GameState gameState) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(gameState)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void remove(GameState gameState) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(gameState)) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void add(GameState gameState) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).manhattanDistance() > gameState.manhattanDistance()) {
                list.add(i, gameState);
                return;
            }
        }
        list.add(gameState);
    }

    public void addWithoutDuplication(GameState gameState) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(gameState)) {
                list.remove(i);
                list.add(i, gameState);
            }
            if (list.get(i).manhattanDistance() > gameState.manhattanDistance()) {
                list.add(i, gameState);
                return;
            }
        }
        list.add(gameState);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    public GameState getNext() {
        return list.remove(0);
    }

    public int getHeuristicOf(GameState gameState) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(gameState)) {
                return list.get(i).manhattanDistance();
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public int getCostOf(GameState gameState) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(gameState)) {
                return list.get(i).getMovementsCount();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

GameState

```
public final class GameState1 {



    public GameState1(GameState gameState) {
       // creates a GameState exactly similar to the one passed
    }

    public GameState1(int[] array, ArrayList<Integer> movements, int type) {
     //...
    }

    public int getMovementsCount() {
     // returns number of movements made so far
    }

    public int[] getPositionsArrayOf(int[] numbersArray) {
        //...
    }

    public int[] getNumbersArrayOf(int[] positionsArray) {
        //...
    }

    public void move(int direction) {
        //...
    }

    public GameState getStateOnMovement(int direction) {
       //...
    }


    public boolean movePossible(int direction) {
        //...
    }

    public int[] getPossibleMovements() {
       //...
    }

    public GameState[] expand() {
       //..
    }

    public boolean equals(GameState anotherState) {
     // returns true if the board state is the same
    }

    public boolean isGoalState() {
      // returns true if it is goal state
    }

    public void print() {
        //...
    }




    public int numberOfInversions() {
        // returns number of inversions
    }

    public boolean isSolvable() {
       //returns true if solvable
    }

    public int manhattanDistance() {
     // returns manhattan distance
    }

   }
```

Sorry for the large code size. I suspect that something is wrong with my AStar algorithm. S0, you probably need not go through the other classes.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read the code exhaustively, but I think it might because you sort the open list just by the heuristic, not by the total cost function. As I'm sure you know...

```
f(x) = g(x) + h(x)
```

Where `g(x)` is the path cost so far, and `h(x)` is the Manhattan distance.

In the method `AStarList.add()` try changing the line

```
if (list.get(i).manhattanDistance() > gameState.manhattanDistance()) {
```

to

```
if (list.get(i).getCost() > gameState.getCost()) {
```

Where `GameState.cost()` is

```
public int getCost() {
    return getMovementsCount() + manhattanDistance();
}
```

Edit: I also noticed that you handling of neighboring nodes looks a bit odd. You should never be removing anything from the closed list. Firstly you want discard the neighbor (i.e. `children[i]`) if the closed list already contains the same or shorter path to that node. Second if the neighbor is new (i.e. not present in open list) or if we have found a shorter path to the same node on the open list, then add it to the open list.

```
boolean presentInOpenList = openList.isPresent(children[i]);
boolean presentInClosedList = closedlList.isPresent(children[i]);

if (presentInClosedList && children[i].getMovementsCount() >= closedlList.getCostOf(children[i])) {
    // Ignore this node
    continue;
}

if (!presentInOpenList || openList.getCostOf(children[i]) > children[i].getMovementsCount()) {
    openList.add(children[i]);
}
```

It might be good to use a `Map` instead of a `List` for your open/closed lists, as you want to make sure you have a single unique entry for each (x,y) coordinate; the one with the lowest cost found so far.

Comment: That is probably the error. I haven't yet taken a formal course in AI so I am not very clear about these concepts. I have done the change. Now, I'm getting the correct answer but the number of states being explored are still too large. Can you please tell if the following things are correct:
1. The list is sorted according to the value of ( number of movements made ) + ( manhattan distance )

Comment: 2. The successor is placed in the open list if a. it is not already present in one of the lists or b. if the ( number of movements made ) + ( manhattan distance ) of the successor is lesser than the one already present in the open or closed list. And the old one which has greater value of f(x) is removed.

Comment: Yes that's correct, though you might as well just use the `g(x)` cost in step 2, since the `h(x)` Manhattan distance will be the same for the same (x,y) coordinates. I think something else is wrong. Will edit post.